# Can screen resolution be set in Active Directory Domain Group Policy?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, screen-resolution

Is there anywhere that screen resolution can be set for the users at the domain group policy level?

Comment: What functional level is your domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct option for doing this in group policy.

What you can do though is write a startup script to do this for you and assign that out via group policy. You'll have to rely on a third party application to change the resolution. I did this once before and was able to find a free one. On my (very quick) search right now, I was only able to come up with [this option](http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm).

Comment: +1 Our district uses that very app.  Although, we stick it in user-logon scripts (rather than per-computer) as needed. Works as described.